# Converting List<string> to IEnumerator<string>

Tags: c#

I cannot figure out how to correctly do this. I am getting this error on the last line of my code. The error says:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (Are you missing a cast?)

Here's the code for the function:

```
public IEnumerator<string> AddElementsAttributesRemoveElementsAttributes()
        {
            List<string> retval = new List<string>();

            try
            {

                    success = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            return retval;

        }
```

How could I fix this? Do I need to somehow cast the return value to a different type?

Comment: Why do you need to return it as `IEnumerator<string>` and not, say, `IEnumerable<string>` ?

Comment: Is it me or does "An explicit conversion exists" not really help at all here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> AddElementsAttributesRemoveElementsAttributes()
```

instead of

```
public IEnumerator<string> AddElementsAttributesRemoveElementsAttributes()
```

You can iterate over the `IEnumerable` number of times however it is not possible to do so using the `IEnumerator`

Comment: `IEnumerator<T>` has a `Reset` method, so it can actually be iterated any number of times. It's also worth noting that certain Enumerable objects create enumerators that cause side effects, and so effectively you cannot use them to create multiple enumerators.  So while the situation you describe can be true in certain situations, it's not true in general, and specifically not true here.

Answer (score 8):

To actually return the list as `IEnumerator<string>` do this:

```
return retval.GetEnumerator();
```

However, it would (probably) make much more sense to return it as `IEnumerable<string>` in which case you have to change the method signature to specify `IEnumerable` instead of `IEnumerator`.

An `IEnumerator` can only be iterated over once, whereas an `IEnumerable` can be iterated over more than once, which is why I think you probably want the latter. But if not, change your return statement.

Comment: `IEnumerator<T>` has a `Reset` method, so it *can* actually be iterated any number of times.  It's also worth noting that certain `Enumerable` objects create enumerators that cause side effects, and so effectively you cannot use them to create multiple enumerators.

Comment: The typical implementation of Reset is to do nothing, so I wouldn't rely on it. It may work for a list, but in general, not so much.

Comment: Sure, and most of those same sources are the same sources are `IEnumerable` objects that can't create multiple `IEnumerator` objects.  In the general case you can't rely on being able to get multiple enumerators from a single enumerable either.  They're *both* single iteration if you don't know something specific about the object.

Answer (score 3):

`List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, but not `IEnumerator<T>`.  An Enumerable can create an Enumerator, it is not one.

While you could ask the `List` for an enumerator from it, and return that, doing so is almost certainly not what you want to do.  It's idiomatic throughout C# to pass around Enumerable objects instead of Enumerator objects and to only use the Enumerator at the last possible moment, generally letting a `foreach` loop do the actual iterating for you.  The fact that a `foreach` loop can accept an `IEnumerable` and not an `IEnumerator` is the primary reason for this practice.

If you change the return type of the method to `IEnumerable<string>` then the return type will be a type your `List<string>` implements, so it will be implicitly convertible and there will be no other changes within this method needed.

Comment: +1 Good explanation. Indeed I missed that, ending up with downvotes!